# Group By Date Range of Sequenced Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, date-range

I am trying to generate a date range sequence and put date in second row if sequencing is break.

```
fldDate        TotalNo
2015-04-01     10
2015-04-02     10
2015-04-03     10
2015-04-04     10
2015-04-05     10
2015-04-06     10
2015-04-07     10
2015-04-08     10
2015-04-09     12
2015-04-10     12
2015-04-11     12
2015-04-12     12
2015-04-20     12
2015-04-21     12
2015-04-22     12
2015-04-23     12
2015-04-24     12
2015-04-25     12
```

I am really stumped

I want this table as

```
StartDate      EndDate      TotalNo
2015-04-01     2015-04-08   10
2015-04-09     2015-04-12   12
2015-04-20     2015-04-25   12
```

Means Either date range breaks or TotalNo change It should create a new row.

I have done it but its not working completely
I am doing like

```
SELECT MIN(fldDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(fldDate) AS EndDate,
       TotalNo
FROM dbo.tbl1
GROUP BY TotalNo
ORDER BY fldDate
```

It will create like

```
StartDate      EndDate      TotalNo
2015-04-01     2015-04-08   10
2015-04-09     2015-04-25   12
```

Comment: This article explains this technique quite nicely. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: you can refer any of the following solutions for Gaps [microsoft technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) 
[sqlmag](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions)
[simple-talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the groups by subtracting an integer sequence from the `fldDate` -- such as provided by `row_number()`.  Consecutive dates will have the same value after the subtraction.  The rest is just `group by`:

```
select min(fldDate) as StartDate, max(fldDate) as EndDate, TotalNo
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     - row_number() over (partition by TotalNo order by fldDate),
                     fldDate) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by TotalNo, grp
order by StartDate, TotalNo;
```