# Group By Date Range of Sequenced Only MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I am trying to generate a date range sequence and put date in second row if sequencing is break by value in MYSQL

```
    fldDate        TotalNo
    2015-04-01       10
    2015-04-02       10
    2015-04-03       5
    2015-04-04       10
    2015-04-05       10
```

I'm looking for the mysql query to get it as follows:

```
    start_dt         end_dt        TotalNo 
    2015-04-01       2015-04-02      10
    2015-04-03       2015-04-03       5
    2015-04-04       2015-04-05      10
```

I found a similar question but I had difficulties translating this in mysql:
[link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472414/group-by-date-range-of-sequenced-only)

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to identify groups of adjacent rows with the same `TotalNo`.  The key is to identify something that identifies these groups.  One measure is the number of values of `TotalNo` that are different from the value in a row.  If your data is not very large, you can use a correlated subquery for this.

Once you have identified the group, the final result is simply aggregation:

```
select min(fldDate) as start_dt, max(fldDate) as end_dt, TotalNo
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.fldDate < t.fldDate and t2.TotalNo <> t.TotalNo
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp, TotalNo;
```

For larger amounts of data, you'd use variables rather than a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT MIN(fldDate) AS start_dt, MAX(fldDate) AS end_dt, TotalNo
FROM (
  SELECT fldDate, TotalNo,      
         @grp := IF(@t = TotalNo, @grp, 
                    IF(@t := TotalNo, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)) AS grp
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @t := 0)
  ORDER BY fldDate ) AS t
GROUP By TotalNo, grp
```

`@grp` variable identifies rows of *consecutive* records having the *same* `TotalNo` value. When there is a break in the `TotalNo` sequence, then `@grp` is incremented by one so as to signify next sequence.